# How to use RoboDialogFragment with a custom layout

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment, roboguice

Can anybody tell me, point e at an example or demo or how to use RoboDialogFragment to inject views on a custom DialogFragment? (Any help or examples in the area of roboguice and fragments would help!)

I'm implementing RoboDialogFragment, overriding onCreateDialog, and inflating my layout - but I cant see how or where I can inject the views (e.g. ListView). I can call view.findViewById - but I was hoping to use injection for this.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: do you want to make custom view dialog?

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact terminology - but I have a class inheriting from RoboDialogFragment, using my own View layout xml (which I inflate inside onCreateDialog).

Comment: if you want to make your fragment dialogs with custome layouts such as listviews and all that you can try my lib on git https://github.com/SiddheshShetye/fragmentDialogLib which offeres lots of things. i haven't uploaded sample though.... if your need is this can explain you about it.

Comment: Its no problem to get it working, I just can't understand how RoboGuice fits into the picture